# How to group elements in a list to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Here is an example of my question:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Then if groupsize = 3, I want:

```
l1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
```

if groupsize = 4, then,

```
l1 = [(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The question above links to an even closer one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/1258041

Comment: Thanks. The links are really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: def group(l, size):
   ...:     return [tuple(l[i:i+size]) for i in range(0, len(l), size)]
   ...: 

In [2]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [3]: group(l, 3)
Out[3]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

In [4]: group(l, 4)
Out[4]: [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9,)]
```

If you decide you want a generator, you can just change `[]` to `()` and get an equivalent of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/1258041) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751478/1258041)) (except for conversion to tuple).

Comment: This works.Thanks. I'll accept this as the answer.